# Unable to play m3u8 file using Azure Media Player

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services, azure-media-player

I have used the following command to generate a `m3u8` file and its corresponding `ts` files. These files are saved in `Azure Blob Storage`.

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 -movflags faststart -s 640x360 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls index.m3u8
```

I have given 'Container' level access to the Azure Blob Container. The URL of the m3u8 is `https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/public/index.m3u8` However, when I pasted this URL in the [Azure Media Player sample application](https://ampdemo.azureedge.net/?url=%2F%2Famssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net%2F3b970ae0-39d5-44bd-b3a3-3136143d6435%2FAzureMediaServicesPromo.ism%2Fmanifest) the video doesn't appear. I get the following error .

What have I done wrong ? Can someone help me out?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The AMP player also does not support HLS natively.  It only supports MPEG DASH in browsers. HLS is only supported on OS's that have that support (iOS)

AMP is only tested with streaming content from the Azure Media Services packager (Streaming Endpoint) and using the manifests from the service.

If you are looking for an HLS player, look to Shaka, HLS.js, Theo Player, Bitmovin.com player or ExoPlayer for Android.

Comment: I have tried with HLS ( https://hls-js.netlify.app/demo/ ) and also with SHAKA Player (http://v1-6-5.shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/) it doesn't display the video. Maybe the FFMEPG code I used hasn't generated the video properly.

Comment: Probably a bad FFMPEG command line.  Did you get it working?  Shaka or HLS.js should have no problem with the m3u8 output from FFMPEG.